# Intento añadir comando 'cd' a un jail de usuario pero no encuentro el bin de este

Tags: linux, ubuntu

estoy haciendo un usuario invitado en mi nuevo sistema **Ubuntu 20** .
Tengo mi usuario **invitado** con su home : **/home/invitado** y su comandos restringidos en **/home/invitado/bin** . Cualquier comando que quiera  que use este user estara ahi dentro, de hecho esta funcionando.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 nov  5 18:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 invitado invitado 4096 nov  5 17:57 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root        7 nov  5 17:58 ls -> /bin/ls*
```

Pero me dispuse a añadirle el comando `cd` para que pudiera navegar entre sus cosas (subdirectorios o lo que sea de su home) pero no encuentra el comando `cd` .
Al igual que para la funcion `ls` hice un `sudo ln -s /bin/ls /home/invitado/bin/ls` fui a intentar lo mismo con el `cd` pero parece que no lo localiza.

¿El comando `cd` no deberia estar entre los comandos core de linux, en `/bin` ?

Answer (score 0):

No existe un ejecutable para el comando `cd`.

`cd` es un comando interno de `bash` (o del interprete de comandos que hayas elegido). Es `bash` quien lee el teclado y ejecuta los comandos que hayas indicado. La mayoría de los comandos (como `ls`) son externos, pero algunos son internos: `cd`, `pwd`, `dirs`, `echo`, etc.

Encontraras la documentación de esos comandos dentro del bash (`man bash`).

Entonces, para que el usuario pueda cambiarse de directorio, sólo necesita acceso a `bash`, condición que ya se cumple al parecer.

Comment: Cierto, es un builtin. Dicho lo cual, si está enjaulado puede evitarse que salte a otro directorio